# Google Chrome reporting revoked certificates

Tags: google-chrome, linux-mint, ssl-certificate

If I try to access a number of websites including main stream banking sites like https://bank.barclays.co.uk on my Linux Mint PC, Google Chrome reports that the certificate has been revoked and will not let me access the site.  I've tried in an incognito window (thereby disabling all extensions) and it does exactly the same.

I've also tried Chromium and Firefox - these both work fine, so as far as I can tell it can't be anything to do with the computer's configuration (e.g. the time).

I've compared the certificate fingerprints reported as okay by Chromium and the one reported as not okay by Chrome - they are the same.  I've also compared the certificate with the one reported on https://www.grc.com/fingerprints.htm and that matches too.

I've also tried going into the settings and clearing all browsing data, but this didn't make any difference either.

Interestingly, some websites like https://youtube.com work correctly.

Having proven I'm not being hacked on my home wifi and that the computer is set up properly (due to Chromium and Firefox being okay), I'm really struggling to see what the problem with Chrome is.

I'm using Google Chrome version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit) on Linux Mint 16 Petra.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of this "revoked" message please?

Comment: Same here with Chromium 37.0.2062.120 on Debian Wheezy. First noted on https://twitter.com/ around 20:00 Dec 17th 2015 UTC.

Comment: Here's an example from a Gandi cert: http://bit.ly/1RrXZc7  I first got the error with the Comodo cert on news.ycombinator.com.

Comment: Common factor for all failing certs for me seems to be the top level CA `Builtin Object Token: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5` with SHA256 fingerprint `9A CF AB 7E 43 C8 D8 80 D0 6B 26 2A 94 DE EE E4
B4 65 99 89 C3 D0 CA F1 9B AF 64 05 E4 1A B7 DF`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An explanation for this is listed here - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=570892

To quote:

> There are >10 versions of the "VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5" certificate. Some of them are signed by the certificate being removed ( https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2015/12/proactive-measures-in-digital.html ), while others are "self-signed". OS X has trusted the self-signed version for some time; however, if you have locally installed one of the "cross-signed" versions, then it will take precedence.

The following steps fixed this for me:

- Go to `chrome://components`
- If *CRLSet* is lower than 2698 click on 'Check for update'
- I then had to restart Chromium, YMMV.

Comment: Brilliant, that seems to have fixed it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that Google decided not to trust the root cert.
They seems rollbacked the change already though.

Google official states as follows,

Proactive measures in digital certificate security
https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2015/12/proactive-measures-in-digital.html

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Comment: The CA cert listed in this link does not appear to be the one causing the issue for me, it has a different fingerprint.